# weird reCaptcha error in PHP

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

I am having a problem with implementing a reCaptcha on my website.

I followed the tutorial here: http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/php.html and implemented just a basic reCaptcha with an error message.

Below is some custom code I use in the file which the form is submitted to:

```
    if (!$resp->isValid) {
        $_SESSION['badLoginCount'] += 1;
        $_SESSION['incorrect-captcha'] = true;
        $_SESSION['incorrect-captcha-error'] = $resp->error;
        header ('Location: ../../signin.php');
        exit;
    }
```

If the user types the incorrect reCaptcha, the page redirects and an error is shown as expected. However when a user enters the correct reCaptcha, isValid still evaluates to FALSE and runs this branch, however $resp->error contains nothing, and this has made it almost impossible to debug.

Has anyone come across this before? I can't find anything online.

Comment: Just to check. Have you checked content of POST fields sent to the recaptcha function?

Comment: yes, the recaptcha_response_field returns the value I entered, the reaptcha_challenge_field returns some hash

Comment: Check http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/troubleshooting.html "It's not working". Review your form and your keys

Comment: Read over the page, everything appears fine (I have it working on a separate page on my site, I pretty much just copy & pasted)

Comment: OK, I tried the example included in the download zip and it worked. I have some suggestions: 1.) did you create the keys as global keys? it could fail if you don't and the server remote_addr doesn't match. 2.) check internet conn as the validation goes up to the validation server and then comes back. 3.) try out the example as I did, but with your keys. Does it work?

Comment: Yes I have a global key, and I have already got it working for a different part of my site with practically the same code. I'm not sure how to go about checking 2), although I can still use it on the other part of the website fine, and my internet connection is great

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out more things to check. :(

Answer (score 0):

A quick and hacky workaround would be to check if `$resp->error` is empty instead.

```
if (!empty($resp->error)) {
    $_SESSION['badLoginCount'] += 1;
    $_SESSION['incorrect-captcha'] = true;
    $_SESSION['incorrect-captcha-error'] = $resp->error;
    header ('Location: ../../signin.php');
    exit;
}
```