# Fail to sent mail PHP recaptcha

Tags: php

I have an issue with recaptcha, Its not sending the mail, even when if I have enter the code correctly, I have try so many times and I have even got someone else to try it and another person and secondly in my `contact.php`

Comment: Fixed indentation. I don't know how you can even read your own code like that.

Comment: @Mike thanks for fixing  the indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is $response, but you're checking to see if $resp is not valid. Change this:

```
    if (!($resp->is_valid)) {
        $captchaErrorMsg = true;
    }
```

To

```
    if (!($response->is_valid)) {
        $captchaErrorMsg = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the way you're checking value of $captchaerrorMsg.

```
<?php if ($captchaErrorMsg){ ?>    
    <p style="color:red">Please enter correct verification code.</p>
<?php } ?>
```

PHP does evaluate what it think you're checking when you don't clearly specify what it is. Therefore does the above code also run when $captchaErrorMsg is 1, when it is true or even when the variable just contains a character, like 'x'.

**You only want to run the above code when error message is true**, therefore you could do like this:

```
<?php if ($captchaErrorMsg === true){ ?>    
    <p style="color:red">Please enter correct verification code.</p>
<?php } ?>
```

If it still doesn't work, you will have to figure out the actual value you're getting. Just do a var_dump of the variable like this:

```
var_dump($captchaErrorMsg);
```

If this doesn't work, look at this workaround at [weird reCaptcha error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603265/weird-recaptcha-error-in-php)

Comment: I have updated my code my question with my code I have now. I took out `<?php if ($captchaErrorMsg === true){ ?>    
    <p style="color:red">Please enter correct verification code.</p>
<?php } ?>` and am showing an error message different. But my email is still not sending even if I says sent.  I

Comment: @bestprogmmaer I recreated the key and made it a global key and I still having recieve the email, it been over 2 hours now. I am using x10hosting. do you think that might be the issue?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that the hosting isn't the issue because you're not getting any mail-failure from theis mailserver.

Comment: Hmm am abit confusing. I have try different emails and it still not working

Comment: did u take a long at my updated code in the question??? I took a new approach to it and it still not working